# JsonSerializer Deserialize byte array

Tags: .net-core, json-deserialization, system.text.json

When deserialising byte array using **Newtonsoft** we can achieve by writing the following code

```
 var stringValue = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(byteArray);
 T data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(stringValue);
```

But how do you do the equivalent **using System.Text.Json**? knowing that it is encoding UTF8?

Comment: Did you read the documentation? You can deserialize using `Utf8JsonReader` like this:

`var utf8Reader = new Utf8JsonReader(jsonUtf8Bytes);`
`weatherForecast = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<WeatherForecast>(ref utf8Reader);`

[MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to#deserialize-from-utf-8)

Comment: the first thing i done is looked at that example and it didnt work :( im passing byte[] and not sure why its not deserializing

Comment: Is there an exception you're getting that you did not share with us?  Or are you getting unexpected results that you didn't share with us?

Comment: @helloworld the example works. If it didn't, everyone using ASP.NET Core 3.1 would have noticed. Post what you *actually* tried, any errors and sample data

Comment: Hi, so i am getting no errors. When I deserialise the object it returns default values. I am passing down Azure Service Bus Message body which is a byte array

Answer (score 4):

This is a working example of how to deserialize with a byte array of a UTF8 string (using **System.Text.Json**):

```cs
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        try
        {
            string str = "{ \"MyProperty1\":\"asd\",\"MyProperty2\":2 }";
            byte[] utfBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str);
            var jsonUtfReader = new Utf8JsonReader(utfBytes);
            ModelDTO modelDTO = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<ModelDTO>(ref jsonUtfReader);
            Console.WriteLine($"First:{modelDTO.MyProperty1}, Second:{modelDTO.MyProperty2}");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

ModelDTO

```
public class ModelDTO
{
    public string MyProperty1 { get; set; }
    public int MyProperty2 { get; set; }      
}
```

Output:

> First:asd, Second:2

Comment: Why do you construct the `utfString`?

Comment: @Joelius No reason other than clarity, we could also do this: `byte[] utfBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str);`

Comment: I don't think it makes it clearer at all. Strings in C# are UTF-16, no matter the way you construct them. So it's just an unnecessary operation that clones a string in a complicated way and IMO rather confusing than helpful.

Answer (score 0):

**Serialize** Byte Array to JSON:

```js
var bytes = MyByteArray;
var jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(bytes.Select(item => (int)item).ToArray());
// jsonString = [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
```

**Deserialize** JSON to ByteArray:

```js
// jsonString = [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
var bytesArray = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<byte[]>(jsonString);
```